# Format loop output

Tags: java, loops

simple question:
this will look like after the run:

```
          text:
          2
          4
          2 text
```

but i want this:

text: 2 - 4

2 text

```
System.out.println("text:");
            for (int i = 0; i < tomb.length; i++) {
                if (tomb[i] % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("" + tomb[i]);
                    db++;               
                }     
            }        
            System.out.println(db + " text");
```

Comment: `println` litteraly means printline, which prints out the text with a new line afterwards. You can use `print` if you want no new line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
System.out.println("" + tomb[i]);
```

to

```
System.out.print("" + tomb[i]);
```

Edit: Actually you also have to change this

```
System.out.println("text:");
```

to

```
System.out.print("text:");
```

Because the printer sets the cursor on the next new line.

Comment: also need to add the dash 2 `-` 4 ;)

Answer (score 4):

use `System.out.print()` everywhere in your code, not `System.out.println();` wich is meant to print on a different line each time